# Phoenix Presence track users across multiple channels

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

So I want to keep track of the current room of each user using the presence behavior. The problem is that I can't/don't know how to update the room_id if a user changes its current room.

`def join("room:" <> room_id, auth_message, socket) do
    IO.puts "joining room:" <> room_id
    if authorized?(room_id, socket) do
      {:ok, assign(socket, :room_id, room_id)}
    else
      {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
    end
  end`

I pass the room_id when a user joins a room and then i made this handler for when he changes between rooms:

```
 def handle_in("room:changed", %{"room_id" => room_id, "user_id" => user_id}, socket) do
    IO.puts "user moved to room #{inspect room_id} "
    Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns.user_id, %{room_id: socket.assigns.room_id})
    IO.inspect(Presence.list(socket))
    push socket, "presence_state", Presence.list(socket)
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

The thing is that for every room he clicks on there is a new entry in the list, so basically he is in all those rooms at the same time. What I want is to only update the room_id when he moves away.

Answer (score 0):

A Channel has a terminate/2 callback which you could use to update presence.

```
def terminate(reason, _socket) do
  Logger.debug"> leave #{inspect reason}"
  :ok
end
```